# Getting the error: Build file 'C:\Users\User\Downloads\grocerydelivery (2)\grocerydelivery\app\build.gradle.kts' line: 1 And I've tried everything

Tags: android, firebase

Basically me and my groupmate are tasked with creating a game and an app of sorts using android studio for our final project however my groupmate's app has been running into this issue the entire day and we've practically tried everything.

Here's the code:

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("com.google.gms.google-services")
}

dependencies {
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:22.3.1")
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0")
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3")
    implementation("com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.8")
    implementation("com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0")
    implementation("androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1")
    implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.7.4"))
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx")
    implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-tflite-acceleration-service:16.0.0-beta01")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
}

android {
    compileSdk = 34
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.grocerydelivery"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro")
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }
}
```

Amongst a plethora of other things, i've tried updating my gradle version and resyncing my gradle files and rebuilding my project, I've even tried deleting the .gradle file to clean the cache.

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Hi there! Could you explain the problem you're having? Does the Gradle build fail? What are the output logs? That'll help us help you better. :)

Comment: Please provide what Ars_Codicis asked for and please also respond using @AlexMamo

Comment: hi yes @AlexMamo  sorry for not including the rest of the logs, but it is too long to put in a reply so i hope a screenshot link will suffice:

https://imgur.com/a/1W24aY2

Comment: Can you please share the content of the other `build.gradle` file?

Comment: hi sorry for the late update, but my groupmate somehow managed to get it working by rebuilding the entire app, but thanks alot for the help!